# How to get number of pods in AKS that were active in a given timeframe

Tags: kubernetes, azure-application-insights, azure-aks

So, I'm having an unexpectedly hard time figuring this out.  I have a kubernetes cluster deployed in AKS.  In Azure (or Kubernetes dashboard), How do I view how many active pods there were in a given time frame?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer, thanks:). I also updated the answer with a detailed query, please let me know if you still have more issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated 0106**:

You can use the query below to count the number of active pods:

```
KubePodInventory 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(2d)//set the time frame to 2 days
| where PodStatus == "Running"
| project PodStatus
| summarize count() by PodStatus
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

If you have configured monitoring, then you can use kusto query to fetch it.

Steps as below:

1.Go to azure portal -> your AKS.

2.In the left panel -> Monitoring -> click Logs.

3.In the table named `KubePodInventory`, there is a field `PodStatus` which you can use it as filter in your query. You can write your own kusto query and specify the `Time range` via portal(by clicking the `Time range` button) or in query(by using [ago()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/agofunction) function). You should also use the [count()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/count-aggfunction) function to count the number.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This will get me going at least